# Faster method to conditionally search nested dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, nested, conditional-statements

I have a nested dictionary that I am attempting to conditionally search through to grab some values. I am iterating through another file and grabbing val1, val2, and val3. From there I search through the dictionary to find an ID based on some conditions.

However, for 55M rows of data this is very expensive. I cannot find anywhere a faster way to do this and I am putting this on a spark job. I tried to have it so that if an ID was found we stopped searching through the dict, but im unsure if I did this correctly.

It appears I go through every key in the dictionary to find values, not sure how to optimize this. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code:

```
for key, val in dict[val1].items():
    if key[0]==val2 or key[1] == val2:
        if len(val3)==1:
            if val3[0]%2==0:
                for key2, val2 in val.items():
                    if key2[2]<=val3[0] and key2[3]>=val3[0]:
                        ID = val2[0]
            if val3[0]%2!=0:
                for key2, val2 in val.items():
                    if key2[0]<=val3[0] and key2[1]>=val3[0]:
                        ID = val2[0]
      if ID!=None:
          break
```

edit:
Input values are like this

```
val1 = zone#
val2 = 'name'
val3 = score in tuple form like (2,)
```

and the nested dictionary looks something like this:

```
{3: defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>.<locals>.<lambda>()>,
                         {('jeff', 'jeff A'): defaultdict(list,
                                      {(23,
                                        41,
                                        28,
                                        40,): [61814],
```

Comment: Rewind a bit. How does this structure exist? Is it something you can change?

Comment: `if val3[0]%2==0:` taking modulo to find keys suggests something is wrong, to me at least

Comment: At the very least, if `val3[0]%2 == 0` is false, you *know* `val3[0]%2 != 0` is true; you don't have to recompute the value.

Comment: Also, `val3` isn't changing: you can determine if `val3[0]` is even or odd *before* the loop.

Comment: @roganjosh it is something I can change. It is meant to take val1,2,3 and find an ID based on a condition. The modulo is one of the conditions, that val3 needs to be even or odd and different tasks are done after that. The code works for 100k points and finishes in 1 min. But I need it to be faster.

Comment: Ok. Can you give a small snippet of starting data and expected output? Something tells me that the setup is wrong, but I can only give a gut-feeling to that

Comment: to optimize your search you can check `if value in dictionary.items()` instead of iterating through all the values in the dictionary in a `for` loop. It will save you time

Comment: So, before all these dictionaries are created. We might be able to push it into pandas/numpy but I'm 95% sure that whatever structure you've set up here is hamstringing you/us. We just can't see the input or output

Comment: Ive edited the post to help.

Comment: @Gal This is the solution, I will post an update in a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Gal posted the answer but here is what the set-up now looks like. Runs over 10 times faster than the for loop iteration.

```
if val2 in dict[val1]:
            if len(val3)==1:
                if val3[0]%2==0:
                    for key2, val5 in dict[val1][val2].items():
                        if key2[2]<=val3[0] and key2[3]>=val3[0]:
                            ID = val5[0]
```

to meet the condition of val2 having two possible outcomes we create two dict's and run this check twice, its much faster now.